Canon A1 Exposure cut short when releasing shutter
I’ve got a strange issue with my Canon A1 which is much more obvious on longer exposures. If I press and release the shutter immediately, the shutter will close straight away even if the exposure is set to say, 4 seconds. If I hold down the shutter it fires correctly, closing after 4 seconds, after which I can release the button.
The self timer also works the same way, the light stops flashing if I release the button but if I keep it held down throughout, it waits 2 or 10 seconds and releases the shutter just fine, and again if I release the button too soon it cuts the exposure short.
It almost feels as if something is trying to reset the shutter and keeping the button held down overrides it?
I’ve taken a first glance at the repair manual and nothing stands out to me, but hopefully someone who’s worked on these might have some sort of pointer.

How new/fresh/old is the battery? Do you have a battery tester or voltmeter you can use to check it?

Only a couple of months old and I’ve tested it, shows as exactly 6V. I tried to pop the top plate off to have a look inside but it’s a huge pain without any tools.

Try flipping the shutter on the eyepiece.  It can effect the meter reading with light coming in the other side when you take your eye away.  In the meantime I'll try to dig out my manual when I get home.

Thank you for the help but unfortunately it’s definitely not a meter issue, even on full manual settings I’m having the same trouble. It does seem to time the shutter right, but it needs a continuous press of the trigger, almost as if something is trying to reset it straight away and it needs to be prevented. I tried having a poke around up top but it’s tricky to take apart without the right tools.
